# How to move business logic out of Spring MVC architecture

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, business-logic

I'm building a new Java web app using Spring MVC framework and, at the same time, i'm building a mobile app using an hybrid framework (Cordova etc...). All modules are in the same project in Intellij and I'm using Maven as repository.
I would like share the business logic between the web app and the mobile app but i cannot move the spring service layer out of the Spring MVC.
I tried to create a new Java module in the project but I cannot understand how can I link the module between the 2 apps, using the right architecture.

Can I move the service layer out of the web app, in an external Java module?
If I cannot do this, how can i manage a shared business logic beetwen the web app and mobile app?

Ask me for any doubts.

Thanks!

Comment: Create a separate jar module and add this module as a dependency in your webapp's and mobile app's pom.xml

Comment: Ideally you have a back-end service and front-end applications that use the service. There's no need to share code then.

Comment: Try to use three tier architecture, which mean dependency as: _client tier(ui, controller layer) -> business logic tier (service layer) -> dao (repository layer)_ . And as @GreyGoose said - you can use separate jar module for all of this layer (for ui you can use war).

Answer (score 0):

That is a very common question people new to Java ask.

What my approach is; when I develop an application, I write the business action and controller classes in separate packages and reference them through JARs.

If you are using spring, you can add some custom functionality to controller classes by extending them (I am assuming you are not using annotations) so that they can execute your business action classes which are provided to them by using beans.